# How to edit a file belonging to other application

Tags: android

I want to edit a file which belongs to a different application. Is there a programmatic way so that I can do it without having to root the phone?

So far, whenever I try to do so, I get "open failed": EACCES (permission denied) error.

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//com.someapp//some_file.xml";
            String backupDBPath = "destfile.xml";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "app found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Err: "+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Toast "app found" appears indicating source file is valid, but immediately after this, it throws open failed, permission denied error.

Tried below within a try block, but seems like - it didn't get executed, rather catch statement is executed.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Comment: If your app used a file, would you want other apps to be able to edit that file? I don't think so

Comment: it is a potential security threat so Android must not allow that, just imagine some fishy app playing around with your sensitive data, so i don't think there will be a work around without root access of the phone

Comment: agreed. But can I at least read it? Or copy to SD. I tried it, same error I got. If there is any way, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. This would include a technically accurate description of what "file which belongs to a different application" means, along with the code that is giving you the error and the stack trace of the error itself.

Comment: Updated the problem statement, hope it helps.

Comment: Is the problem more intelligible now?